# Minus 5 hours 30 minutes from a date

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column-formula, date-time, calculated-column

I have a column of type as date and time. I want to minus 5 hours 30 minutes to produce a new time in a new column - Please advise?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by creating new calculated column, setting the data type to `Date and Time`, choosing the `Date & Time` in `Date and Time Format:` and using the following formula (put your original column name instead of dt1):

```
=dt1-(5.5/24)
```

Explanation can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)#add-dates).

Full dates can be added/subtracted with +/- so 5.5/24 would calculate to 5.5 hours.